# Use of undeclared identifier 'AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager'

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, cocoapods

I installed the latest version of AFNetworking using pods. And when I try to do

```
[[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
```

I am getting

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager'.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you `#import "AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.h"`?

Comment: @PetahChristian I noticed I only import the AFNetwork.h. I import AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.h and it is working. Thanks for point it out.